# Hyperlink в Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

В столбце Datagrid находятся ссылки, которые формируются из 3-х свойств класса,  но по клику по ссылке ничего не происходит.

Xaml:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Имя">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Uid, StringFormat=}http://site.com/profile/{0}}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        <Run Text="{Binding First_name}"/><Run Text="{Binding Last_name}"/>
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

code-behind:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

В чем проблема?

UPD:
Читал, что у Datagrid есть столбец datagridhyperlinkcolumn под ссылки, но как я понял, его нельзя сформировать из нескольких элементов.

Comment: то что находится блоках Run не относится к формированию ссылки. для формирования ссылки из нескольких свойств можно написать конвертер

Comment: @S.Kost, Можете привести пример такого конвертера? Хоть убей, ничего не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для формирования ссылки из нескольких свойств удобно использовать мультиконвертер. Доменное имя можно передавать в параметре конвертора, ну или по желанию.

xaml-разметка

```
<Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" Name="hyperLink">
    <Hyperlink.NavigateUri x:Uid="uri">
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource linkConverter}" ConverterParameter="http://site.com/profile/">
            <Binding Path="Name"/>
            <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
   </Hyperlink.NavigateUri>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=hyperLink, Path=NavigateUri}"/>                
</Hyperlink>
```

сам конвертер

```
public class LinkConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //values - ваши свойства
        string domainName = (string)parameter;
        string uriString = String.Join(string.Empty, values); //1-ый аргумент метода - разделитель ваших свойств, можно заменить на "/"

        string link = string.Concat(domainName, uriString);
        return new Uri(link);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```